# multitouch rotation and scale object in project tango app in Unity

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

How do I add multitouch effect on Lenovo Phab 2 pro in unity environment, which does rotate and scale based on touch. For example, if i want to rotate any simple object i can use touch gesture to do that. Can someone guide me for that ?

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you should show what you already tried and what doesn't work instead of asking people to solve a problem for you.

That being said, Unity provide a way to deal with multi touch through the Input class (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html)

It might however be simple to look for an existing library handling gestures for you.

Touchscript works well for instance: http://touchscript.github.io/